# How to open an R data file in Excel Power Query?

Tags: r, excel, powerquery

How can I save data in an R compressed file format and then open it in Excel Power Query? I've opened in PowerBI Power Query no problem by setting the R path and using R.Execute(), but Power Query in Excel only has an RData.FromBinary() function.

Hopefully it can be loaded into Excel without any external dependencies as I'd like to switch from accdb files on a shared drive for the purpose of sharing easily refreshable data sets.

I tried exporting with these 3 methods:

```
saveRDS(tmp, "c:/users/ian/Documents/CRAN_mirrors.rds")
save(tmp, file="c:/users/ian/Documents/CRAN_mirrors.RData")
save.image(file="c:/users/ian/Documents/CRAN_mirrors.RData")
```

And tried importing with both:

```
= RData.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\ian\Documents\CRAN_mirrors.rds"))
and
= RData.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\ian\Documents\CRAN_mirrors.RData"))
```

Either of those import attempts gives me the following error:

```
DataFormat.Error: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Analytics.Modules.R.ErrorHandling.RException.Primitives.NotValidRDataException' was thrown.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.